# Better way of adding copies of an object to a container

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, shared-ptr

I have a class `Bar` which stores objects derived from `BarItem`:

```
#include <list>
#include <memory>

class Bar {
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<BarItem> item_ptr;

    void add_item(item_ptr item) {
        items_.push_back(item);
    }

private:
    std::list<item_ptr> items_;
};
```

I have another class `Note` which is a subclass of `BarItem`. Currently to add a copy of a `Note` object I am doing:

```
Bar my_bar;
Note my_note;

my_bar.add_item(Bar::item_ptr(new Note(my_note)));
```

Which is a bit ugly; I would like to know if there is a better way or a way to automate this?

Comment: any reason you're not doing 

`my_bar.add_item(Bar::item_ptr(my_note));`

Comment: @Hans my_note is a Note object not a pointer to Note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually avoid the copy (in C++11 you can make it a move), but you can "automate" it so you save a few keystrokes by overloading the `add_item` function for each type (that may be child of `BarItem`).

```
template <class T>
typedef enable_if<is_base_of<BarItem, T>::value,void>::type add_item(const T& item) { /* or T&& */
    items_.push_back(item_ptr(new T(item)));
}
```

Comment: Can I ask what the advantage of adding the enable_if is? Wouldn't you get a compilation error anyway if `T` is not a subclass of `BarItem`?

Comment: @Rarge: Yes, you would get a compile error. There would be no difference for eg. `Note`, so it could be a way to go. The `enable_if` cause the templated overload to go out of the way when `T` is not a child of `BarItem` and not a `shared_ptr<BarItem>`, but something that could be converted to it, like a `shared_ptr<Note>` (assuming `Note` is a child of `BarItem`). Without SFINAE, you'd get an ambiguity error; with it, you'll get a call to your original function with conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can move that ugly part in the function itself as:

```
template<typename ItemType>
void add_item(ItemType item) //change the signature
{ 
    items_.push_back(new ItemType(item));  //add the copy!
}
```

and call it as:

```
my_bar.add_item(my_note);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pointers in containers is one way of reducing the copying of objects.  But the way you're handling the creation of the Note object involves making a copy of it via the copy constructor!

Can you avoid having an object and instead have a pointer to the object?  You could do this by putting the creation inside a function (factory).  That function will take the constructor's arguments, new the object and return a smart pointer.